# Conflict of routes in express

Tags: node.js, express

I'm building the documentation for my API, I created a route for it as `localhost:4000/docs`, but for some reason when typing`localhost:4000` the browser loads the contents of the documentation, I'm forgetting something else I can not imagine anything.

app.js

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()

require('./middlewares/md-bootConfig')(app)//start config
require('./routes/Login')(app) //route login
require('./routes/Home')(app) //route home
require('./routes/Doc')(app) //route documents api

module.exports = app
```

static folder

```
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const logger = require('morgan')
const path = require('path')
const express =  require('express')
module.exports = app => {
    app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../../../docs')))
    app.set('json spaces', 2)
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));
    app.use(bodyParser.json());
    app.use(logger('dev'));
}
```

route /docs

```
const path = require('path')
module.exports = app => {
    app.get('/docs', (req, res) => {
        res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '../../../docs', 'index.html'))
    })
}
```

the docs folder is at the root of the project.

path `/`

```
const env = process.env.NODE_ENV
module.exports = app => {
    app.get('/', (req, res) =>{
        res.send({
            version: '1.0.0',
            status: 'API on-line',
            environment: env
        })
    })
}
```

How do I enter `localhost:4000` and load the JSON status from the API and not the load `/docs`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The response is falling back to your static route.

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../../../docs')))
```

Add an additional route for '/'

```
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
})
```

Make sure this route is defined **BEFORE** your `app.use(express.static` line